# How do I Substract values in one column with the values of another in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

I want to see which country has the biggest difference between the column "Gold" and "Gold 1". The index currently is the countries.

As an example, with Afghanistan, it would be 0 - 0 = 0. I do this with every country and than the highest number in that list is my response. That's how I figured I want to do it.

Does anyone know how I can do that? Or is there a built-in function that can calculate that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subtract these two columns using the built-in vector subtraction:

```
df1['Gold'] - df2['Gold 1']
```

Answer (score 0):

The country with biggest difference is

```
df.Gold.sub(df['Gold 1']).idxmax()
```

The biggest absolute difference

```
df.Gold.sub(df['Gold 1']).abs().idxmax()
```

You can also sort this by the difference

```
df.loc[df.Gold.sub(df['Gold 1']).sort_values().index]
```

Or the absolute differences

```
df.loc[df.Gold.sub(df['Gold 1']).abs().sort_values().index]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try out the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['Afgh',0,0],['Agnt',18,0]], columns = ['Country','Gold','Gold1'])
df['GoldDiff'] = df['Gold'] - df['Gold1']
df.sort_values(by = 'GoldDiff', ascending = False)
```

`df` is just a test dataframe based on yours above. `df['GoldDiff']` creates a new column to store differences.

Then you can simply sort the values by using the `sort_values` function from pandas. You can also add the option `inplace = True` if you want to modify your dataframe as the sorted one.

Comment: Glad it helped out mate, please accept as answer if it helped you solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers